# Add two matrices, one of which is multiplied with an int. CUDA

Tags: matrix, cuda

I'm trying to do what the title says. Do this calculation: A*X + Y, where A is an `int`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 1024

__global__ void calculate(int A, int X, int Y, int S) {

        int tID = blockIdx.x;
        S[tID] = A*X + Y;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int A, S[N], X[N], Y[N], i;
        int dev_A, *dev_S=0, *dev_X=0, *dev_Y=0;
        float time;
        cudaEvent_t start, stop;
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);

        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_S, N*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_X, N*sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_Y, N*sizeof(int));
        cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
        for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
                X[i] = i;
                Y[i] = i;
        }
        cudaMemcpy(&dev_A, &A, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(&dev_X, X, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(&dev_Y, Y, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        calculate<<<N,1>>>(dev_A, *dev_X, *dev_Y, *dev_S);
        cudaMemcpy(S, dev_S, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        printf("Array X:\n");
        for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", X[i]);
        }
        printf("Array Y:\n");
        for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", Y[i]);
        }
        printf("Array S:\n");
        for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
                printf("%d\n", S[i]);
        }
        cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
        printf("Elapsed Time: %f\n", time);
        cudaEventDestroy(start);
        cudaEventDestroy(stop);
        cudaFree(dev_S);
        cudaFree(dev_X);
        cudaFree(dev_Y);

        return 0;

}
```

Once I do compile with nvcc I get this error:

```
(7): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type
1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003d10_00000000-6_saxy.cpp1.ii".
```

I'm a newbie at CUDA and just started. Can you help please ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel code is slightly wrong. As David Kernin already said, you are using integers. But you should use integer *arrays* instead. Additionally, for the `tID` you have to use the `threadIdx.x` and **not** the `blockIdx.x`. Or in the more generic form:

```
__global__ void calculate(int A, int *X, int *Y, int *S) {

    int tID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    S[tID] = A*X[tID] + Y[tID];
}
```

This will allow you to treat matrices that are larger than the maximum value of `threadIdx.x`, because you can address the entries even when using more than one block, by invoking this with

```
calculate<<<numThreadsPerBlock,numBlocks>>>(A, dev_X, dev_Y, dev_S);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help ! one last question. I am the one that declares the number of threads per block and the number of blocks or the gpu does ?

Comment: You have to define it. Your GPU may have a max. of 512 threads per block. If your matrix is greater than that, you have to specify multiple blocks. For example, if your matrix has 700 elements, then you have to define numThreadsPerBlock = 512, numBlocks=2. **BUT** then you also have to pass the size of your matrix to your kernel and check `if (tID<matrixSize) { /* compute...*/ }`, to avoid accessing invalid matrix entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
S[tID]
```

is an integer, you can't access that as an array. It's not CUDA's fault.

Comment: so i just write S = A*X + Y ?

Comment: This is not a CUDA problem, I recommend studying C++ better.. but I'll give you a hand: passing an integer is not working because an integer is JUST ONE value.. and you're trying to access value[0], value[1], value[2], etc.. per each thread. You should pass a pointer to an array of values, enough for each thread to use those values.

Comment: I know how to do this program in C++, but cuda has confused me a lot.

Comment: Think about it: also in C++ calculating S and not returning it is pointless anyway. With CUDA you also have the fact that your code is concurrently run by multiple threads

Comment: so i will do the following declaration: S[N] = A*X[N] + Y[N] ?